# Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start. This is error snapshot

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, web.xml

Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start. This is error snapshot

**I am unable to identify why this problem is occur. when i change something in xml files then this problem start.I send a small snapshot of my problem. Help me to resolve this issue.
  After change in this file mentioned below i got error. I send a small snapshot of that file also.Advance thanks.

Project is in maven, spring , mysql**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/shoot]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/shoot]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5202)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 20 more



</pre>
```

- File :

  ```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.jwt" />

  <!-- Getting Database properties -->


  <mvc:annotation-driven />


  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


  <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <!-- DataSource -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      id="dataSource">

  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jwt"></property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Transaction -->
  <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
      ">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, spring-context.jar is not inclded in your application. If you are using maven, please check dependency for spring-context jar file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupid>org.springframework</groupid>
  <artifactid>spring-context</artifactid>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```